# Problem installing - "there is no suitable CSPRNG installed on your system"

Tags: php-errors, install

Can anyone help me with this?
Im trying to installed 5.3.2 and this message is appearing.

```
Exception Caught
There is no suitable CSPRNG installed on your system
ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Compat/Random/random.php:176

Stack Trace: Please include when reporting this error
#0 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Compat/Random/random_int.php(156): random_bytes(8)
#1 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Encrypt/Encrypt.php(285): random_int(-9223372036854775807, 9223372036854775807)
#2 ee/installer/controllers/wizard.php(878): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Encrypt\Encrypt->generateKey()
#3 ee/installer/controllers/wizard.php(272): Wizard->do_install()
#4 [internal function]: Wizard->_remap('do_install', Array)
#5 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Core/Core.php(241): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Core/Core.php(110): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->runController(Array)
#7 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Boot/boot.php(151): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->run(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Request))
#8 admin.php(153): require_once('...')
#8 admin.php(153): require_once('...')
```

Answer (score 2):

CSPRNG stands for [cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) which is a library added to PHP from version 7.0 onwards.  From version 5.2 onwards it was possible to install [an additional module](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) on your server to provide this service.

So my guess is that the php system on the server you are using is running some flavour of php5, and that this additional module is not installed.

Strong recommendation is therefore to adjust your server to be one that is running a version of php7.  If this is not possible, then discuss with your server administration the possibility of adding the necessary CSPRNG module to whatever version is being used.

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot for your informative and swift answer. I was wondering if it was due to the php version. Ill check with the host. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old thread, but if someone is having same problem when running Windows server with PHP 5.6, you need to make sure you have [CAPICOM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/getting-ready-to-use-capicom) installed and `com_dotnet` extension is included in `php.ini`